# Stacks iteration python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iterator, stack

Ok so im trying to input a word in a stack and I want to print all of them after I input a string. So I can only print them one at a time. I tried using a for loop outside but Stacks are apparently not iterable. So I iterating it inside the stack. It still is not working.

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def push(self,items):
        self.items.insert(0,items)
    def pop(self):
        for x in self.items:
            print( self.items.pop(0))

    def show(self):
        print (self.items)

s = Stack()
s.show()
placed = input("enter")

item = s.pop()
print(item, "is on top", s)
```

Comment: About your stack design, why not use `.append()` and `.pop()` instead? Add items to the end of the list, and `.pop()` with no arguments removes them again from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `Stack` class a [`__len__` method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), this will make testing if the stack is empty easier:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def show(self):
        print (self.items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)

stack = Stack()

stack.push('World!')
stack.push('Hello')

while stack:  # tests the length through __len__
    print(stack.pop())
```

Note that I simply `.append()` to the end of the `.items` list, then later on `.pop()` (no arguments) again, removing from the end of the list.

To make your class [an iterable type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), you'd need to add at least an [`__iter__` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__), optionally together with a [`.__next__()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next):

```
class Stack:
    # rest elided

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            return self.items.pop()
        except IndexError:  # empty
            raise StopIteration  # signal iterator is done
```

Comment: Ok wait how do i print the Hello backwards? thats why i needed to iterate?

Comment: Ok i got it you just need this.         return self.__items[len(self.__items)-1]

Comment: Just use `[-1]`; select the last element with a negative index.